# Adicionar linha a DataGrid com DataSource definido

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Tenho um `DataGridView` que tem o `DataSource` *setado* com `List<MinhaClasse>` e gostaria de adicionar uma nova linha ao mesmo.

Sei que isso não é possível usando o método `AddRow()` do `DataGrid`.

Existe alguma forma que eu possa fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível fazer isso, *setando* um `BindindList<>` como `DataSource`. Assim, sempre que um item for adicionado da `BindingList<>` ele será automaticamente inserido no `DataGridView`.

```
var source = new BindingList<MinhaClasse>();
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
source.Add(new MinhaClasse { Nome = "João", Idade = 32 });
```